# Make sense of this mess!

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Give me the correct answer to the question below.

**What is this?**

---

[image]

```
                       ◯
                               ⨂
                       ⨂
                       ◯
                ⨂
                ◯
                       ◯
                                           ⨂
                                              ◯ 
                                              ◯   
         ◯       
                ⨂
```

Comment: Having seen the accepted answer, this puzzle doesn't work on mobile, the page rendering/scaling doesn't maintain the relative positioning required.

Comment: @fljx Aah, I noticed that but if you tilt it, using wide screen, it does maintain the relative positioning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is:

> **PIGPEN PUZZLE**

First consider the chain of symbols in the top 'header row'...

> These are the grid-spaces of the [pigpen cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher) in order. i.e. The rows of a 9-square octothorpe-shaped grid (used for letters A-R), and the sectors of the 4-triangle cross-shaped grid (letters S-Z):
>
>  [image: Standard Pigpen cipher decoder]
>
>  You can see this more clearly if you divide the symbol chain like so:
>
>  [image: Symbol chain with red line separators]

Now consider the circles and crossed-circles beneath...

> In each case, (i) the horizontal position of the circle shows which part of the Pigpen cipher grid to use (by seeing which of the header row symbols it falls directly beneath), and (ii) an uncrossed circle indicates we are supposed to use the 'dotted' Pigpen grids, while a crossed-circle means we do *not* need a dot.
>
>  The first letter encoded here is therefore a 'P', being in the column below the 'bottom-left grid corner' symbol, and with a dot (indicated by the circle character).

If we repeat this process for all the circles and crossed-circles...

> ...and read off the corresponding letters from top to bottom of the diagram, we get the following solution message:
>
>  **PIGPEN PUZZLE**
>
>  [image: The diagra decoded]

Comment: That's the answer, nice visuals and well done!

Comment: I was about to ask for an image explaining the alignment step, but it looks you added one while I was typing :-)